# Expo custom native: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn"

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

I have an `expo` project that has `android` and `ios` separate projects, which I have used `@react-native-google-signin`, I want to run this app with my ios emulator. Below is the error that I got when I runs `pod install`

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn":
  In Podfile:
    ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn (from `../node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn (from `../node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Pod file:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/package.json')"`), "native_modules")

require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}

platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods',
  :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'TaytayTianggeMarketplace' do
  use_expo_modules!
# @generated begin react-native-maps - expo prebuild (DO NOT MODIFY) sync-e9cc66c360abe50bc66d89fffb3c55b034d7d369
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native-maps/package.json')"`)
# @generated end react-native-maps
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled] || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Dir.pwd}/.."
  )

  # Uncomment to opt-in to using Flipper
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work
  #
  # if !ENV['CI']
  #   use_flipper!()
  # end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)

    # This is necessary for Xcode 14, because it signs resource bundles by default
    # when building for devices.
    installer.target_installation_results.pod_target_installation_results
      .each do |pod_name, target_installation_result|
      target_installation_result.resource_bundle_targets.each do |resource_bundle_target|
        resource_bundle_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

The new version will get this error
Using version 8.0.0 fix it. remove "^" before version
@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "8.0.0"

Comment: This works for me, thank you for the solution. I do feel uneasy about going back to version 8.0.0 from version 10.x.x. Is this ok? Do you know why this happens?

Comment: 9.0.2 works as well. Strange why latest is not so good..

Answer (score 0):

Try bumping the ios version. `platform :ios, '13.0'` -> `platform :ios, '14.0'` in the Podfile.
This might be better than using an older version of the auth library.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the releases notes is work for me:

https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/releases/tag/v11.0.0

> target ios 13.4 for expo SDK 50 podspec. If you're on SDK 49, use v10

So, in my package json:

> "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "10.1.1",

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).